# There was an error processing coverage reports in codecov

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, travis-ci, kotlin, codecov

I'm using kotlin, gradle, travis ci and codecov. The build seems to fail at codecov
https://codecov.io/gh/config4k/config4k/commit/01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.typesafe:config:1.3.1'
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest:1.3.5'
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main'
    test.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/test'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        html.enabled = false
        xml.enabled = true
        csv.enabled = false
    }
}
```

.travis.yml :

```
language: java
sudo: false
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
script:
  - ./gradlew test jacocoTestReport
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

logs :

```
2016-11-19T19:52:01+09:00 seterror  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/commits/01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d/statuses bot=mmorihiro code=200     
  2016-11-19T19:52:01+09:00 notify  skip-no-files-found  error=Error   
  2016-11-19T19:51:36+09:00 upload  no-reports-generated  error=Error   
  2016-11-19T19:51:36+09:00 upload  Processed file name=jacocoTestReport.xml language=jacoco   
  2016-11-19T19:51:36+09:00 upload  Upload archived download   
  2016-11-19T19:51:31+09:00 upload  
WAITING FOR CI TO COMPLETE

  2016-11-19T19:51:30+09:00 upload  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/contents/codecov.yml bot=mmorihiro code=404  
      {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}    
  2016-11-19T19:51:30+09:00  Upload accepted ci=travis build=15.1   
  2016-11-18T21:35:56+09:00 seterror  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/commits/01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d/statuses bot=mmorihiro code=200     
  2016-11-18T21:35:56+09:00 notify  skip-no-files-found  error=Error   
  2016-11-18T21:35:31+09:00 upload  no-reports-generated  error=Error   
  2016-11-18T21:35:31+09:00 upload  Processed file name=jacocoTestReport.xml language=jacoco   
  2016-11-18T21:35:31+09:00 upload  Upload archived download   
  2016-11-18T21:35:25+09:00 upload  
WAITING FOR CI TO COMPLETE

  2016-11-18T21:35:25+09:00 upload  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/contents/codecov.yml bot=mmorihiro code=404  
      {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}    
  2016-11-18T21:35:25+09:00  Upload accepted ci=travis build=15.1   
  2016-11-18T21:24:36+09:00 seterror  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/commits/01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d/statuses bot=mmorihiro code=200     
  2016-11-18T21:24:26+09:00 notify  skip-no-files-found  error=Error   
  2016-11-18T21:24:26+09:00 notify  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/commits/01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d/statuses bot=mmorihiro code=200     
  2016-11-18T21:24:08+09:00 upload  no-reports-generated  error=Error   
  2016-11-18T21:24:08+09:00 upload  Processed file name=jacocoTestReport.xml language=jacoco   
  2016-11-18T21:24:08+09:00 upload  Upload archived download   
  2016-11-18T21:23:48+09:00 upload 

WAITING FOR CI TO COMPLETE

  2016-11-18T21:23:48+09:00 upload  GET /search/issues?q=01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d+repo:config4k%2Fconfig4k+type:pr+state:open bot=mmorihiro code=200  ratelimit=29/30 reset=1479471888     
  2016-11-18T21:23:48+09:00 upload  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/commits/01ac813e057b3de25274b03c07ab39f348d5074d bot=mmorihiro code=200     
  2016-11-18T21:23:48+09:00 upload  GET /repos/config4k/config4k/contents/codecov.yml bot=mmorihiro code=404  
      {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}    
  2016-11-18T21:23:48+09:00  Upload accepted ci=travis build=14.1
```

Do you know any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an issue mapping files back to your GitHub repository layout. Please add the following to your `codecov.yml` file:

```
fixes:
  - "io/github/config4k::src/main/io.github.config4k"
```

I'll make a pull request to work with you on it.